# Google Credential Provider for Windows with Yubikey 2FA

Tags: google-authenticator, yubikey

Can I use my Yubikey hardware 2FA with Google Credential Provider for Windows (GCPW)?

At the moment I am asked to sign in again the only option is Google Authenticator, and a few more but the Yubikey option does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue here.
Unfortunately this ist not supported :(

Note: **USB security keys aren’t supported by GCPW.**
If you enforce security keys, users can still sign in to their device with Android and iOS built-in security keys.
Or, when prompted for 2-Step Verification, they can click "Try another way" and use another 2-Step Verification method if one is available.
**If no other method is available, users can't sign in to the device.**
To modify your 2-Step Verification methods, go to the 2-Step Verification setup guide.
[Installing GCPW](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9543613?product_name=UnuFlow&hl=en&visit_id=637983146568526571-654408321&rd=1&src=supportwidget0&hl=en)

Comment: That is bad now the whole company has hardware security keys but can't use them. 
And the other methods are slow and less secure. Would be nice if Google could fix this.